# Converting WordPress themes to Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, wordpress-theming, drupal-themes

I've seen that Drupal 6 has a really poor set of themes compared to, for example, WordPress. Do you know good resources/links for converting WP themes to D6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book [Front End Drupal: Designing, Theming, Scripting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137136692) includes a few pages that do a very good job of explaining the basics of converting a Wordpress themes to Drupal 6 themes.

Alternatively, the following links may also help:

- [Convert a Word Press theme to Drupal](http://groups.drupal.org/node/7144)
- [How to Create a Drupal Theme / Convert Wordpress Theme into Drupal 6.x Theme](http://freedrupaltheme.com/how-create-a-drupal-theme-convert-wordpress-theme-drupal-6x-theme)

Answer (score 1):

Also check out the [WP Theme](http://drupal.org/project/wp_theme) module for Drupal 6. It's currently under development, but provides implementations of the common theme functions used in WordPress themes, mapping them to Drupal equivalents. That allows you to use a fair number of WordPress themes directly.